# arrow in plot matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am unable to get the arrow to display like I want it.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b = np.arange(5)*-1E-4
a = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a,b, linewidth=3, color="k") 
plt.arrow(1,-0.00010,0,-0.00005, shape='full', lw=3, length_includes_head=True, head_width=.01)
plt.show()
```

As far as I understand, this should produce an arrow starting at (1,-0.00010) and ending at (1,-0.00015)
But the result is a much longer line, no longer looking like an arrow, and not starting and stopping at the right points.

[image]

Comment: I assume the bad indent on your `.arrow` call is not like that in your real code?

Comment: My guess would be it's the `0` dx.  Your arrow has no width.

Comment: @Mark If the arrow has a width, it is displayed just as long as the y-axis, as shown on the image linked in my post (I am new to stackoverflow, therefore the link instead of an image)

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] and explain what your desired plot should look like

Comment: @DavidG I edited the question now, I hope this explains my problem better :)

Answer (score 24):

Because you are using such small scales, some arguments which you have not explicitly passed to `plt.arrow`, will use their defaults, which in your case will not give a nice outcome.

Looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html), if no value for width is passed then the default value is 0.001, then the head width will be 0.003 and the head length will be 0.0015. Because the head width is too small using the default values, and the head length is much too big you get the output seen in the question

Therefore, you need to pass in the arguments `head_width` and `head_length`:

```
plt.arrow(1, -0.00010, 0, -0.00005, length_includes_head=True,
          head_width=0.08, head_length=0.00002)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!! I actually want to turn the arrow the other way. So the head is at the starting point. I have tried "head_starts_at_zero". But this command also seems to be giving problems. Any tips?

Comment: @K.Soerensen I can't get `head_starts_at_zero` to work either, maybe a bug? In any case you can change the coordinates to have the arrow the other way around: `plt.arrow(1, -0.00015, 0, 0.00005, ...)`

Comment: As to what `head_starts_at_zero` means, maybe read through [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12768). Also see the last comment of that issue thread to see what I would recommend doing here.

Answer (score 9):

You can draw arrow with annotate.[matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

```
a = np.linspace(-2,2, 100)
plt.plot(a, a**2)
plt.annotate("here", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(0, 2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```

Comment: There is some bug and the arrows don't show up with the correct lengths

Comment: DavidG answers explains the problem with scaling in the original question. The three lines above a generic answer. Retested and it behave exactly as I would expect it.